# Javascript not properly calling API

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have my website call my login API, which I have tested from a separate app, and through Postman, and it runs fine.  However when I run it through my website, it is not calling the API with the actual values inside the html input item.

Below is my HTML of my attributes:

```
  <div class="container">
    <label for="uname"><b>Username</b></label>
    <input id= "username" type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

    <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
    <input id= "password" type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>

    <button id="loginButton" type="button" class=""">login</button>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
    </label>
  </div>
```

Below is my code for my website API call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = function () {
            var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

           console.log("login button clicked");
           var usr = document.getElementById("username").value;
           var psw = document.getElementById("password").value;

           console.log(usr);
           console.log(psw);

           xhttp.open("GET", "http://serverAddress/checkHash/"+usr+"/"+psw+"/", true);
           xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
           xhttp.send();
           var response = (xhttp.responseText);
           console.log("user logged in");
           console.log("the response is:" + response);

           //var value = (usr.concat(psw));
           //console.log('concat value of both usr and psw is:');
           //console.log(value);
           if(response != "no") {
              //this means the credentials are right
              localStorage.setItem("session", usr);
              location.href = "userSearch.php";
           } else {
              window.alert("Incorrect credentials");
           }
          };
      </script>
```

Below is my Server code:

```
app.post('/createPhysician/', function(req, res) {

    console.log("below is the req body for createPhysician");
    console.log(req.body);

    var createPromise = interact.createPhysician(
        req.body.firstName,
        req.body.lastName,
        req.body.yearNum,
        req.body.position,
        req.body.isAttending,
        req.body.highRiskTrained);

    createPromise.then(function(createResponse) {
        res.json("successful"); // returns the physicianID for the createUsers
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(req.body);
        res.json("Terrible job you botched it");
    }); 
});
```

Below is my interact sql file:

```
   createPhysician: function(
        firstName,
        lastName,
        yearNum,
        position,
        isAttending,
        highRiskTrained)  {
        var qry = "insert into Physician (firstName, lastName, yearNum, position, isAttending, highRiskTrained) values ('"+firstName+"', '"+lastName+"', "+yearNum+", '"+position+"', "+isAttending+", "+highRiskTrained+");";
        console.log("below is query ran in DBINteract");
        console.log(qry);
        return runQuery(qry);
    }
```

the error I am getting is as follows:

```
below is the username given to server.js
[object HTMLInputElement]
below is the value of pass from app
[object HTMLInputElement]
below is the value from server side
TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
```

Comment: It is a bad idea to send username and password in the url

Comment: @Skyler bad idea to send username and password in any part of an HTTP request payload in general, but putting it as the path just makes it even easier to intercept.

Comment: yes should use https.

Comment: Did you check browser console for errors?

Comment: @Vasan the lines `console.log(usr)` and `console.log(pwd)` don't return anything, which I believe is causing the issue.  But I am unsure as to why they would not have a value here